# What's the difference between these two narrowing conversions?

Tags: c++

Here is a code snippet with two lines performing narrowing conversions. Why does one of them compile fine, but the other one doesn't? They are doing the same thing as far as narrowing conversions go.

**This is a contrived example. I know I could have just used `nums.size()` to get the size. This is not the point of the question.**

```
std::vector<int> func(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    int works_fine = nums.end() - nums.begin(); // this compiles
    return std::vector<int>({ nums.end() - nums.begin() }); // this does not compile
}
```

The line with the `return` statement gives this warning:

warning: narrowing conversion of '__gnu_cxx::operator-<int*, std::vector >((& nums)->std::vector::end(), (& nums)->std::vector::begin())' from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector >::difference_type' {aka 'long long int'} to 'int' [-Wnarrowing]

Comment: What do you intent the line to return? A vector of `size` zero-initialized elements or a vector with one element with value `size`?

Comment: What don't you understand from the warning:  narrowing conversion of 'long long int' to 'int'? Why don't you use `num.size()`?

Comment: Why not use `nums.size()` instead of what you're doing?

Comment: I don't understand two things. (1) how do I convert an iterator to an index. (2) the line above the return statement is doing exact same conversion but compiles just fine.

Comment: @Ninja. Because this is a contrived example. What I really want to know is how to convert a vector iterator to an index.

Comment: @user17732522 I intend to return a vector with one element. The value of that element is the size of the passed-in vector.

Comment: You convert it by subtracting it from `begin`, just like the shown code does. The compiler diagnostic is due to completely unrelated reasons.

Comment: `it - vec.begin()` works, but the result is not an `int`. To avoid the warning you need an explicit cast.

Comment: What is your question? How to convert an iterator to an index, or why the warning is raised?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with that code. Your busybody compiler is telling you that you might not be smart enough to understand the code that you’ve written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with how you obtain the index of the end iterator.

---

However, there is a problem with your `std::vector` initialization. There are two relevant constructors. One that accepts a single argument for a parameter of type `std::vector<int>::size_type` (usually `std::size_t`) and one that has a single parameter of type `std::initializer_list<int>`.

The issue is that`std::initializer_list`'s are special in overload resolution and always preferred over conversion to other parameter types in list-initialization, i.e. when the argument is a braced-init-list (i.e. not an expression but instead a starting with a `{`).

So the constructor chosen here is the one that takes the `std::initializer_list<int>` and that initializes the vector with the elements of that list.

Then the problem is that to construct the `int` element of the `std::initializer_list<int>` you must convert `nums.end() - nums.begin()` to type `int`. The type of `nums.end() - nums.begin()` is `std::vector<int>::difference_type` (usually `std::ptrdiff_t`), which is likely to be wider than `int`, so that this is a narrowing conversion.

And narrowing conversions are not permitted in list-initialization. (GCC is already unusually permissive by only providing a warning instead of failing to compile it. Other compilers are not that permissive, but both behaviors are conforming.)

---

According to your comments this really is the constructor that you want to use, so:

To make it compile properly you need to explicitly cast `nums.end() - nums.begin()` to `int`:

```
std::vector<int>({static_cast<int>(nums.end() - nums.begin())});
```

or you can use an equivalent constructor that doesn't use list-initialization:

```
std::vector<int>(1, nums.end() - nums.begin());
```

In either case, the warning/error is there for a good reason: What do you want to happen if the index is larger than `int` can hold? Both solutions given above ignore this and will simply store an unintended value in the vector. To do this properly you need to rethink the `int` element type for the vector. It should probably be `std::ptrdiff_t` or even better `std::vector<int>::difference_type`. Alternatively you can add an out-of-range check and e.g. throw an exception or do whatever is sensible to your use case.